# How to capture customer's credit card details via PayPal on my checkout page?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, paypal

On my ecommerce website, I don't want customers to leave my website and be directed to PayPal when paying via credit card. Is there a good plugin that shows a PayPal credit card form on my checkout page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WooCommerce PayPal Pro Payment Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-pro-payment-gateway/), it basically does what you are looking for.

> Will it offer on-site checkout so my customers don't have to leave
>   the site? 
>   **Yes**

Answer (score 0):

Like @castiblanco said, if you’re using WooCommerce, you can use the plugin mentioned. Should you be using anything other than WC for your store, there is the possibility of other plugins.

Bottom line is that you’d need to use the Pro Payment Gateway.